# How to get C# to detect first windows logon since computer startup?

Tags: c#, windows, sessionid

I'm a beginner in C# programming and have absolutely no idea how to solve the following puzzle (no matter the program language).

As little explanation, I am about to write a program restoring custom startup sound for Windows Vista (and higher), running non-elevated, without being a service and placed in current users Autostart. But my app should play the startup sound ONLY, if MS doesn't already play the logon sound. This should be determined by the following dummy script:

```
if (CurrentUserHasAutoLogin = Yes OR (CurrentUserAccountIsActiveOnly = Yes AND NoPasswordSet AND NotInDomain))
AND **SinceLastRestartItstheVeryFirstLogin = Yes**
{
Play.Startup.Sound
} else {
//do nothing (Windows plays Logon sound instead)
}
```

Its almost done yet, except the bold typed part.
It is the condition "SinceLastRestartItstheVeryFirstLogin" I have problems with. Here is what I have tried already (and expect to work):

- The code should at least be compatible down to Windows Vista/7 (my current target framework is 4.0)
- Since its an autostart app and have to be installed by user rights, it won't survive a re-logon.
- My first attempt was to query `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`, but unfortunately on Windows Vista/7 the counter will be resetted to 0 once you logout/login with same user again (on Windows 10/11 it works, but my app should work for Vista/7 too), so every logon 1 would be displayed.
- The `idea of creating a registry/file counter` entry after first logon and delete when shutdown isn't perfect too since abnormal shutdown (e.g. power outage) might interfere with it. It should be determined without redirected input.
- A (dirty) workaround might be searching for SYSTEM process `SearchIndexer.exe` since it gets started after the first logon and will outlast logout. But some people tend to disable Windows Search for better performance and the process never starts then, so its not reliable. Anyway, this method seems kind of weird.

Does anyone have an idea how to identify whether it's the first Windows logon since computer started or not, when app runs with non-elevated rights and invoked by Autostart?

Comment: _this method seems kind of weird_: This application seems _kind of weird_. What is the purpose of this application and how will it improve the lives of those who use it?

Comment: The app restores the missing sound events on Windows: On Windows 7 only custom startup sound is missing from mmsys.cpl, from Windows 8 on startup/shutdown/logon/logoff were disabled but can be re-enabled and from Windows 10 on they become functionless even after re-enable their entries. So the intention of it is to give people back their freedom of custom sound schemes and make them happy.
A better question is whether you can help me with it or not...

Comment: Everything older then Windows 10 is "end of life" therefore unsupported. i doubt anyone has specifics in his head about this without trying and as its eol almost no one still has a system to try it. If you are a beginner as you say you should try finding a problem where you can learn something about programming. Not some crazy specifics of a past operation system. You are just learning something of a dead operating so its also dead useless knowledge.

Comment: @Tu deschizi eu inchid: It seems weird to you because you don't know the whole code. Watching for Security Events in task planer and play sounds when they get triggered is not enough. On Windows Vista/7 only startup sound missing. I have to avoid double/missing sounds when logoff (simple, I can close the app on these OS right after logon), but for logon itself MS makes it really complicated: If logon doesn't need input, startup sound is played (from my app). But as soon you have to select the user or/and enter the password logon sound is played instead (onboard). This explains the question.

Comment: @Ralf: Its a project in my spare time. Is it forbidden trying the app to be downwards compatible? Nowhere on Stack Overflow stands: Don't ask  questions for OS that are EOL.

Comment: My point wasn't that you shouldn't ask my point was its very unlikely to get help because of that EOL state. And as you stressed the beginners aspect yourself its not something that seems very helpful in learning programming when that was the intention here. I wish you luck in finding something that knows.